# Add index-number as HTML attribute with Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Okay,

I am iterating over all my existing entries (@entries) and try to set a slide for that up.

Everything is working, but I need a specific HTML attribute to be set.
I tried it as this (view.html.slim):

```
- @entries.drop(1).each.with_index do |lidata, index|

  li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="index"
```

Unfortunately that's not working. It should look like so:

```
li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"
li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"
...
```

How can I add the index-value as attribute there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **string interpolation**. Try:

```
- @entries.drop(1).each.with_index do |lidata, index|
  li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="#{index}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, did not think of that. Works flawlessly fine!